# JavaScript intellisense.js file

Tags: javascript, com, visual-studio-2015, intellisense

My question is what am I doing wrong to not get intellisense to come up in Visual Studio?

I am attempting to create a JavaScript program that wraps a COM object, extends it a little and provides intellisense for the COM object properties.

JavaScript file:
jscript.js

```
function wrapper(inject)
{
    inject.state = 0;
    return inject;
}
```

Intellisense file:
jscript.intellisense.js

```
function _wrapper()
{
    return {
        /// <field name="state" type="Number">stores state of object</field>
        state:0,
        /// <field name="comprop" type="Boolean">this is a com property</field>
        comprop:true
    }
}

intellisense.annotate(wrapper, _wrapper);
```

HTML file:
index.html

```
<script>
    var com = new wrapper({});

    com.*  // <-- the intellisense should be reflected here but it isn't

</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure this one out and after a long time of trial and error, I came up with this solution:

Even though MSDN says to use the intellisense.annotate function, I found that the only way to get it to work properly was to declare the object fully inside the intellisense file.  So my new intellisense file looks like this:

jscript.intellisense.js

```
function wrapper()
{
    /// <summary>Wrapper that works</summary>
    /// <param name="inject" type="String">Inject my COM object into here</param>
    /// <returns type="ComObject" />

    return {
        /// <field name="state" type="Number">stores state of object</field>
        state:0,
        /// <field name="comprop" type="Boolean">this is a com property</field>
        comprop:true
    }
}
```

With no intellisense.annotate() function call.  This is a far simpler solution and the only one I could find that keeps intellisense for more than one tree level.

For me, this is mostly untested, if anyone sees an issue with this solution, please provide an answer, I will leave the question open.